# Ajax not working on live server Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I have this ajax request working on my localhost. But when i upload to my share host they throw 500 internal server error. I'am passing the _token.

```
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $('.enviarForm').on('click',function(){
        var data =  { 
                'email': $('#email').val(), 
                'phone': $('#phone').val(),
                'consulta':$('#consulta').val(),
                '_token':token,
                "_method": 'post'
            };
            console.log(data);
        $('.enviarForm').html("Enviando...<img src='{{asset('img/loading-form.gif')}}'' alt=''>");  
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',         
            url:'http://har***ine.com/public/testPost',
            data:data,
            success: function(msg) {
                if(msg['message'] == 'success'){
                    $('.enviarForm').html("Enviado");
                    $.notify({
                        // options
                        message: 'Tu consulta fue enviada. Dentro de 24hs te responderemos a tu email o teléfono. Muchas gracias.' 
                    },{
                        // settings
                        type: 'success',
                        placement: {
                            from: 'bottom',
                            align: 'center'
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $('.enviarForm').html("Enviar");
                    $.notify({
                        // options
                        message: 'Error: Por favor complete todos los campos e intente nuevamente.' 
                    },{
                        // settings
                        type: 'danger',
                        placement: {
                            from: 'bottom',
                            align: 'center'
                        }
                    });
                }
            }       
        });
    });
```

> My test controller are this:

```
     public function testPost(Request $request){
         return response()->json(['message'] => 'success'); }
```

My route file are this:

```
Route::post('/testPost',[

    'uses' => 'ContactController@testPost',

    'as' => 'contacto.testPost',

]);
```

I tried a lot of things but i don't make it work. The csrf token its okey, .htaccess are ok and the most important thing is working on localhost. Any one have any idea? I'm making crazy with this.

Comment: The first thing to do with 500 error is __read logs__

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks that solve my problem :).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to send the token as header value rather than body. First, remove '_token':token, from data. Then:

```
$.ajax({
headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : token
        },
            method: 'POST',         
            url:'http://har***ine.com/public/testPost',
            data:data,
....
```